# Global filter not working in p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have applied Global Filtering on a `<p:dataTable>` but that's not working at all. The getter is being called in the Bean but the `<p:dataTable>` is not being updated according to the search.

The code is:

```
<p:dialog id="searchStdentsDlg" header="Search Students" widgetVar="srchStdents" modal="true">
    <h:form id="searchStdentsFrm">
        <p:dataTable id="srchStdentsTble"
                     var="student"
                     value="#{viewStudentsBean.studentsList}"
                     widgetVar="srchStdentTbl"
                     emptyMessage="No students found with the given criteria"
                     filteredValue="#{viewStudentsBean.filteredStudents}">

            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputPanel>
                    <h:outputText value="Search Students:" />
                    <p:inputText id="globalFilterStdents" onkeyup="PF('srchStdentTbl').filter()" style="width:200px" placeholder="Enter keyword"/>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>

            <p:column id="stdentId" headerText="Id" filterBy="#{student.id}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.id}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentFirstName" headerText="Firstname" filterBy="#{student.firstName}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.firstName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentLastname" headerText="Lastname" filterBy="#{student.lastName}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.lastName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentFathername" headerText="Father name" filterBy="#{student.fatherName}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.fatherName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentGender" headerText="Gender" filterBy="#{student.gender}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.gender}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentDOB" headerText="Date Of birth" filterBy="#{student.dob}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.dob}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentSkype" headerText="Skype/Email" filterBy="#{student.skypeOrEmailId}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.skypeOrEmailId}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentPhone" headerText="Phone No" filterBy="#{student.phoneNumber}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.phoneNumber}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentAddrs" headerText="Address" filterBy="#{student.address}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.address}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentCountry" headerText="Country" filterBy="#{student.country}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.country}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentJOD" headerText="Joining Date" filterBy="#{student.dateOfJoining}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.dateOfJoining}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentGenralRmrks" headerText="General Remarks" filterBy="#{student.generalRemarks}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.generalRemarks}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

I have another datatable in which Global Filtering is working absolutely fine. 
That code is:

```
<p:dialog id="searchTchrsDlg" header="Search Teachers" widgetVar="srchTchrs" modal="true">
    <h:form id="searchTchrsFrm">
        <p:dataTable id="srchTechrsTble"
                     var="teacher"
                     value="#{viewTeachersBean.teachersList}"
                     widgetVar="srchTchrsTbl"
                     emptyMessage="No Teachers found with the given criteria"
                     filteredValue="#{viewTeachersBean.filteredTeachers}">

            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputPanel>
                    <h:outputText value="Search Teachers:" />
                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('srchTchrsTbl').filter()" style="width:200px" placeholder="Enter keyword"/>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Id" filterBy="#{teacher.id}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{teacher.id}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Firstname" filterBy="#{teacher.firstName}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{teacher.firstName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Lastname" filterBy="#{teacher.lastName}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{teacher.lastName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Contact No" filterBy="#{teacher.contactNo}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{teacher.contactNo}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Address" filterBy="#{teacher.address}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{teacher.address}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Joining Date" filterBy="#{teacher.joiningDate}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{teacher.joiningDate}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Qualification" filterBy="#{teacher.qualification}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{teacher.qualification}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Subjects" filterBy="#{teacher.subjects}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{teacher.subjects}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Languages" filterBy="#{teacher.languagesProficiency}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{teacher.languagesProficiency}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Total Exp" filterBy="#{teacher.totalExperience}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{teacher.totalExperience}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Salary" filterBy="#{teacher.salary}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{teacher.salary}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Total Leaves" filterBy="#{teacher.totalLeavesLimit}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{teacher.totalLeavesLimit}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

I am using PrimeFaces 5.0 and JSF 2.2

PS: There are no exceptions on server side and no errors in browser console.

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Finally i found the solution. The id of <p:inputtext> used for global filter always needs to be "globalFilter". Means if you have more than one <p:inputtext> or anyother components used for custom global filters they all need to have the same id "globalFilter".

Comment: your comment solved my issue!! Was troubleshooting my global search function for hours, turns out I named my <p:inputtext> as "global-filter" -_-